# Why won't my images change when clicked even though the logic seems pretty straight forward?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to display a new image upon clicking on the current image.  The problem's that upon clicking on `img-1`, it some how skips to `img-3`.  However, if I remove the the second `if()`, it correctly goes to the next image (`img-2`).

How's this happening and how can I fix it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<img id="the-image" onclick="clickedImage()" src="https://www.folkdeal.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/f/d/fd-ea10150-1.jpg" alt="image down"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    let theImage = document.getElementById('the-image');

    let index = {
        "img-1" : "https://www.folkdeal.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/f/d/fd-ea10150-1.jpg",
        "img-2" : "http://image.en.yibada.com/data/images/full/66771/the-legend-of-zelda-japanese-hepburn-zeruda-no-densetsu-is-a-high-fantasy-action-adventure-video-game-series-created-by-japanese-game-designers-shigeru-miyamoto-and-takashi-tezuka.png",
        "img-3" : "https://www.geekisus.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/01_1575-11-400x400.jpg"
    };

    let clickedImage = () => {
        if(theImage.src === index["img-1"]) {
            theImage.src = index["img-2"];
        }

        if(theImage.src === index["img-2"]) {
            theImage.src = index["img-3"];
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try using `else if`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
 theImage.src = index["img-2"]
```

this will be true

```
 if(theImage.src === index["img-2"])
```

and then

```
 theImage.src = index["img-3"];
```

will be executed, effectively skipping the second image. You probably want to change the second `if` into an `else if`.